# JmsTemplate bean missing in springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, spring-jms

After changing my springboot version from 2.7.5 to 3.0.6 I am getting this error

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com....JmsNotifier required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
  - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' in your configuration.
```

I am getting this error from this service class which works properly in springboot version 2.7.5

```
@Service
public class JmsNotifier {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
   //

}
```

Here is the dependency

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:3.1.0'
```

Am I missing any additional dependencies?

Comment: The best way to deal with dependencies is to generate a proper gradle or pom.xml from here: https://start.spring.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache ActiveMQ "Classic" support is [removed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#removed-support) from Spring Boot 3.0.0. So we need to use this dependency instead:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis'
```